# How do I explode a string in PHP but keep them on the same line?

Tags: php

I am pulling a field from an Oracle dB with PHP. The field stores values like `firstname:surname`. How do I explode on `:` from field so the values will stay on the same line in an html table?

```
<?php
include_once 'dB/oraConfig.php';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT Name FROM Orders');
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
       echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";

    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Comment: So your desired result is going from "firstname:surname" to "firstname surname"?

Comment: what's the name of the field you are trying to explode ?

Comment: its the name field from SELECT Name FROM Orders, so the field has all the values at first:last ie: Bob:Smith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to apply this to your code

```
//the variable you want to fix is in tmp 
$tmp = "firstname:surname"; 
//the field gets the result without ':' 
$field = explode(':' , $tmp)[0]." ".explode(':', $tmp)[1] ;
```

Comment: This won't work in PHP versions prior to 5.4, from http://fi1.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php : "Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]"

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to echo "firstname surname", separated by a space, you can just

```
echo str_replace(":", " ", $item);
```

repace all colons with spaces.

Comment: I think that this is a better and simpler answer than the accepted answer. You'll get all the values(in case there are more than two values separated with a ":") and you won't get a notice/warning that you're trying to access an undefined key in an array(when there is no ":" in the text from the DB).

Answer (score 0):

If `$str` will be string in format firstname:surname:

```
$str="firstname:surname";
$arr=explode(":",$str);
echo $arr[0]." ".$arr[1];
// firstname surname
```